# modifying contents of local variable of a function in a subfunction through pointer

Tags: c++

I have the following sample code. Just wanted to know if is valid to take address of a local variable in a global pointer and then modify it's contents in a sub function. Following program correctly modifies value of variable **a** . Can such practice cause any issues ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int*> va;

void func()
{
   int b ;
   b = 10;
   int * c = va[0];
   cout << "VALUE OF C=" << *c << endl;
   *c = 20;
   cout << "VALUE OF C=" << *c << endl;


}
int main()
{
     int a; 
     a = 1;
     va.push_back(&a);

     func();

     cout << "VALUE IS= " << a << endl;

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code as you have posted is safe, but curious to know, is this just an academic exercise, or are you writing it for some specific purpose?

Answer (score 2):

This is OK, as long as you don't try to dereference `va[0]` after `a` has gone out of scope. You don't, so technically this code is fine.

That said, this whole approach may not be such a good idea because it makes code very hard to maintain.

Comment: How would one dereference `a` after having gone out of scope? Can you give an example?

Comment: @David: The pointer is still in `va`, so `*(va[0])` would cause undefined behaviour after `a` has gone out of scope.

Comment: main calls func1 which calls func2.  var a is defined in func 1 and pushed to va in func1.  func2 using va is ok, main using va is trouble.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that if your program grows you could forget about a change you made in some function and get some weird errors you didn't expect.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly valid as long as you call `func()` while being in the scope of `a`. *However,* this is not considered to be a good practice. Consider

```
struct HugeStruct {
  int a;
};

std::vector<HugeStruct*> va;

void print_va()
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < va.size(); i++)
    std::cout<<va[i].a<<' ';
  std::cout<<std:endl;
}

int main()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    HugeStruct hs = {i};
    va.push_back(&hs);
  }

  print_va(); // oups ...
}
```

There are 2 problems in the code above.

1. Don't use global variables unless absolutely necessary. Global variables violate encapsulation and may cause overlay of variable names. In most cases it's much easier to pass them to functions when needed.
2. The vector of pointers in this code looks awful. As you can see, I forgot that pointers became invalid as soon as I left for-loop, and `print_va` just printed out garbage. The simple solution could be to store objects in a vector instead of pointers. But what if I don't want `HugeStruct` objects to be copied again and again? It can take quite a lot of time. (Suppose that instead of one `int` we have a vector of million integers.) One of the solutions is to allocate `HugeStruct`s dynamically and use vector of smart pointers: `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<HugeStruct>>`. This way you don't have to bother about memory management and scope. Objects will be destroyed as soon as nobody will refer to them.